# error opening file: play

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when a play a launch file to extract images.
[FATAL] [1395007907.659016454]: Error opening file: play

here is my launch file, saved in /home/usr/fi.launch   and heres what i run roslaunch fi.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140566/error-opening-file:-play/) by [pronik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13416/pronik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

delete "play from args="...".

The rosbag package provides a program named "play" which you run as a node via the type="play" part of .  (Your usage here is reminiscent of the command-line tool rosbag.)

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-17**:
This was a bug in the tutorial. Fixed: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data